# Get GoogleDocs Selection from DIV and replace it (JAVASCRIPT, XUL)

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to develop a Firefox extension that gets the selected text from a google word doc and replaces it with another text (any text).

If i inspect the selection with Firefox's InspectElement i find that the selection is a DIV with the class name = "kix-selection-overlay kix-overlay kix-unprintable kix-overlay-under-text" .

How do i get the text from the DIV and then modify it ? All the methods that worked in a normal webmail, even in a excel spreadsheet(google docs) failed to work in a google doc word document.

For now i just managed to obtain the element with :

- var focusedElement = document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement;

Thank you a lot !
Alex!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google Docs has its own selection system, instead of using the Javascript range document it creates divs for every line that is selected behind the text. It does this so that collaborative users can have different colors for their selections and because the range object has annoyances with the way that it handles nested elements and offsets.

Google Docs would have an internal selection object as well as copy and paste functionality. You simply need to look through the code and find what methods are called by the oncopy and onpaste event handlers.

- Ryan